# Memory allocation crashes the OS. Who's to blame beside the OS

Tags: c++

This short snippet

```
#include <new>

int main(){
  while(true){
     try{
        new char[0x10000000];
     }catch(std::bad_alloc bac){
     }
  }
}
```

apparently crashes the entire operating system when compiled as a 64 bit application and run on a 64 bit Windows system.

This is a valid c++ program. How can this happen? Isn't the msvc compiler at fault here too?

All other compiler/system combinations left the system sluggish at worst.

Don't try this at home. user Christophe tried this on his system and it crashed.

To commenters: I'm not interested in debugging. This is a valid c++ program. My code is not at fault. I'm curious what might induce this behaviour.

Comment: Wha? .. How does the crash look like? Can you also get your computer to emit smoke?

Comment: Both blue and black screen.

Comment: @CaptainGiraffe: If you see a bluescreen, then you encountered a Windows or driver bug.  That should _not_ happen.

Comment: @Captain, if you're not much of a photographer, then by all means write down the blue screen scriptures and copy them back into your question. Without them, we cannot possibly understand your problem.

Comment: @MooingDuck So my surprise is. Can I crash 64-bit windows by asking for memory?

Comment: @Captain, you can if one of your memory chips is buggy.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi This should be reproducible.  I'm not currently on a windows machine.

Comment: @Captain, memory chips failing is usually not reproducible when one is not running on the very same chips.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi This is reproduced in a lab room with lots of different hardware.

Comment: It happens if either there's something not right with your hardware (e.g. bad memory, broken processor), but more likely is that some driver is not coping well with out of memory. Since machines nowadays often have "enough" memory nearly all the time, drivers developed by people that don't agressively TRY to break things sometimes don't cope with low memory conditions very well.

Comment: @Captain, a lab room? You can definitely find photographers among the crew there I believe. *Please provide the information required to understand your problem.*

Comment: I just rebooted, having totally lost control of the machine.   It seems that the system tries to allocate memory, get a lot of page faults (listening to my disk). Impossible to interrupt.   No blue screen, just a frozen PC.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi a computer lab at a uni.

Comment: I agree with Frederic: The exact details of what blue-screen content is very useful to identify what has gone wrong. It's not unusual that a large room with lots of different hardware has, for example, the same Antivirus software, which is a good candidate for this sort of driver problem (AV software usually has a driver component)

Comment: @Christophe Sorry about that.

Comment: @MatsPetersson  would you mind provide your speculation as an answer?

Comment: Isn't memory on Windows lazily allocated, so actually it performed on first memory write?

Comment: To OP: You may enable saving `memory.dmp`: http://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/235496 So after blue screen crash may be analyzed (but it requires WinDbg and kernel symbols, it is quite complicated)

Comment: @myaut: But if you compile in debug mode, the runtime will fill uninitialized memory with a "poison", so the memory will be written to immediately after allocation.

Comment: I don't believe this. Compiler will optimize this line away because it's not doing anything. Also unix system doesn't actually allocate the memory unless you access it

Comment: @texasbruce, it has side effects of calling global `operator new()` (who knows what will it do)

Comment: @texasbruce: If I were to run this on my Linux machine, it would "hang" - until either the program finishes on its own accord, fails to allocate more memory or gets killed by the OOM killer. Trust me, I have tried [by accident, not on purpose like this].

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One quite plausible scenario for "blue screen when an application is using a lot of memory" is a driver that crashes. There are two common problems here:

1. Driver that can't allocate memory and doesn't detect the `NULL` returned by allocation function when it couldn't allocate memory", resulting in a NULL [or close to NULL] memory access.
2. Driver doesn't properly "lock" it's memory buffers, leading to pages that the driver "needs" being swapped out when it comes to use the page - this leads to "IRQL Not Less or Equal" blue-screen, which is caused by OS detecting that a page-in request happens when the driver is in a mode where the scheduler is "locked". In other words, the driver asked for "no other task must run until I finish this", and then a page-fault happens that is a request to page in a page from the swap, which indeed requires a different task [the swapper process] to run - can't have the cake and eat it, so OS says "No can do" - can't continue at that point, since the driver is not able to access memory, can't switch to another task, so we can't do anything other than "report error and stop".
3. A third alternative is that the driver detects that it can't allocate memory, but decides that it can not continue and then issues its own blue-screen by calling the "I want to bluescreen now" function in Windows. Drivers that are well written should not do this, but like some driver writers still decide that this is a "good idea".

Sorry, it's been about 11 years since I wrote windows drivers, so the exact error codes one can expect here have gone missing. I think 7B for IRQLNotLessOrEqual, and 0xC00000005 for the access of unmapped memory (NULL access etc).

The fact that several different machines behave the same can easily be explained by many machines having either similar hardware (e.g. same printer, USB [mouse or keyboard?] or CD-ROM drive that is flaky), or by having the same antivirus software - AV software always has a driver component to "hook" into other processes and such.

Given that "really running out of memory" is not so common these days, not so skilled/experienced/conscientious developers may well not test properly with either fake out of memory or real out of memory situations, and thus not detect that their driver fails in this situation.

To give more details, we'd need to know at least the blue-screen "code" (four to five hex-numbers at the top of the screen)

Assuming there is some point to debugging this sort of failure, you can either set up windows to store a a dump (or mini-dump) when it crashes, or use a second PC to connect WinDBG as a remote debugger [or some other remote debugger] to the machine that is crashing - when a machine blue-screens, it will stop in the debugger before restarting, so you can see what the state of the system is, including looking at the callstack of the code that caused the crash - which typically will show what component is actually causing the problem. However, unless you actually have a good contact with the driver developers (at the very least an email address to the relevant support people), it's unlikely much can be achieved to solve this.

Comment: Excuse my ignorance, what's new char[x]; in the question anything to do with drivers?

Comment: Directly, it hasn't. But `new char[x]`, with a fairly large `x` and in a loop will fairly soon have taken up all the memory in the machine, and the machine starts swapping to disk (if there is a swapfile). At that point, a driver may well struggle to get the memory it needs (either because the swapping process has filled all the "unswappable" memory, or because things are swapped out that the driver hadn't expected to swap out).